# Will be worried or will be worry

Tags: grammar

I saw a man commented in instagram, he said "she will be worried" and i think it's wrong, but then i browsed up and find it was trus. As i know, it should be "she will be worry"

So, what you say? Which one is right? Even if it's same, there must be some different between them

Answer (score 2):

*She will be worried* is the conventional and 'correct' way.

I say, *She will be worry* is grammatically 'incorrect' in all contexts I know of. 
You might have learned the use of the verb in this way from where it's been used in 
other contexts, for example: *She will be a worry* or **She will worry**.

Comment: "she will be worried" is a passive form, is it right? Or still just an active form?

Comment: From what I understand about active voice, When the agent (the one who acts on the object) is in the subject position, then it is not passive voice. In this case, 'She' is the agent and the subject... It should be active as the other examples also are.

Comment: _Worried_  here is an adjective meaning _anxious_.

Comment: A reference to your answer would give your response more "meat", though it is correct.  "Will be worry" makes worry into a noun.

Comment: It *can* be grammatical, but you need to force it into the right context. *"Who's she dressing up as this Halloween?"* ***"She will be Worry."***

Comment: @user341152 Like Kate Bunting says, "worried" is an adjective in this case, though the distinction between passive verb and adjective following "be" is not always easy to make. One trick is to see if you can replace "be" with "seem" – if you can, you're dealing with an adjective rather than a verb ("she will seem worried"). There are a number of tricks like this, and still it's sometimes hard to tell :)

Comment: @user347464 You're absolutely right that if the agent is the subject, then the clause is active, not passive. In "She will be worried" there is no agent though, right? There is no-one doing something actively (to something or someone else), so "she" is not the agent in this case, see?